# IE11: script7002 XMLHttpRequest network error 0x2efd could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Tags: jquery, http, https, internet-explorer-11

My web application is running in a WebLogic application server in https mode. I am trying to call a Spring boot application converted to exe file on the client machine using a jQuery AJAX request to `http://localhoost:8090/check-connection`

I am getting this error in the IE11 console:

> script7002 xmlhttprequest network error 0x2efd could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Does anyone know a solution to this problem, or can anyone explain why I get error?

```js
var URL = 'http://localhost:8090/check-connection';
jQuery.ajax({
  url: URL,
  method: "GET",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    getSelectFolders();
    
    if (!isFolderSelected() || isDocumentSelected()) {
      alert("please Select Folders Only.")
      return false;
    }

    openJupiterWindow("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JupiterJSPs/print.jsp?indexClassId=" + jQuery("#ics").val() + "&key=export&items=" + JSON.stringify(selectedItemsArr), "Print Window", '700', '600');
  },
  error: function(e) {
    var r = confirm("Print Service is not installed in this machine. Do you want to install it?");
    if (r == true) {
      var printDownload = document.createElement('a');
      printDownload.setAttribute('href', "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/PrintService.exe");
      var htmlBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
      htmlBody.appendChild(printDownload);
      printDownload.click();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Which line of code does the error point to? Have you tested in other browsers like Edge, Chrome and so on to see if the issue still exists?